# "Merging" two books in Calibre's index

Tags: pdf, calibre, mobi

I've bought some digital books, and I was supplied with both the `PDF` and the `mobi` format.

Adding them to Calibre, they are treated as different books, and strangely they also have different metadata (the PDF versions miss publisher and author information).

[image]

**Is there a standard way to tell Calibre that they are the same book?** Sure I could use it to manually convert one into the other one, but I would rather keep the original one in both formats.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

My current version has a "Merge book records" menu entry. Just select all entries belonging to the same book, then right-click and find "Merge book records" under "Edit metadata".

The first clicked book will be the main one, whose metadata will be picked in case of conflicts.

[image]

The manual way would be:

1. Delete all but one of the duplicate entries (NOT the files!)
2. Open the metadata editor for the remaining entry (right-click, Edit metadata individually)
3. Click the red book with the plus sign in the top right to add the other format's files
4. Click OK when you're done.

Comment: That's it, thanks! I'd just add that the first _clicked_ book will be the "main" one, which will keep the metadata in case of conflicts.

Comment: But I'm trying this right now, and It doesn't work. In fact it always picks up the book it wants. I tested doing right click on the first and second book, but all the time it picks up the one it wants.

Answer (score 0):

My Solution

Select both book records in clibre books list

Right Click on the selection > Edit Metadata > Merge book records

You will see 3 options

1. Merge into first selected book - delete Others
2. Merge into first selected book - keep Others
3. Merge only formats into first selected book - delete Others

Select the one that fits your need.